# PPO model learns well then predicts only negative actions

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm using openai's gymnasium python package to create a PPO model to play a simple grid based game, similar to gym's GridWorld example. Most actions will result in a positive reward. Usually there is only one action that will result in a negative reward.

During the learning phase, I can by printing out in the environment's `step()` function, that the model is doing pretty well. It rarely chooses the actions that would have negative rewards.

When I try to test the model after and predict on a new game, it freaks out and chooses a few good actions followed by only choosing the only action that gives a negative reward. Once it finds the bad action, it sticks with it until the end.

Is there a bug in the code for testing/using the model to predict?

```
env = GameEnv()
obs = env.reset()
model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10_000)

obs = env.reset()

for i in range(50):
    action, _states = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(int(action))
    env.render()

    if done:
        obs = env.reset()
```

Sample output from learning:

```
action, reward = 2, 1
action, reward = 3, 1
action, reward = 2, 5
action, reward = 0, 1
action, reward = 0, 9
action, reward = 1, 1
action, reward = 3, 1
action, reward = 3, -5
action, reward = 2, 1
```

Sample output from testing:

```
action, reward = 0, 1
action, reward = 1, 5
action, reward = 2, 1
action, reward = 0, 1
action, reward = 0, -5
action, reward = 0, -5
action, reward = 0, -5
action, reward = 0, -5
action, reward = 0, -5
action, reward = 0, -5
action, reward = 0, -5
action, reward = 0, -5
...
```

Comment: Training for 100k timesteps, the model makes it about 15 moves in before choosing bad actions. Training for 300k timesteps, the model makes it about 25 moves in. But why or how could it possibly be deciding to do the only bad action over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in specifying `deterministic=True` on `model.predict()`.

When the `deterministic` flag is true, the model always picks the same action for a given state, explaining the fixation on a negative action. Flipping this flag to false resulted in the expected behavior.

Changing this line:
`action, _states = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)`

to this:
`action, _states = model.predict(obs, deterministic=False)`
fixes the problem.

Comment: That implies that the agent has not learned enough. The optimal policy of a RL agent is, if learned properly, the greedy policy. I advice you to let it learn more.